# GridSplitter height doesn't respect the grid row containter height

Tags: wpf, xaml

Using the following piece of XAML you can still grab the grid splitter at the bottom, why?

```
<Grid Background="Blue" Margin="20">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border Background="Red" />
  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Shouldn't the row height of 0 prevent you from grabbing the grid splitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is a normal behavior. `GridSplitter` represents the control that redistributes space between columns or rows of a `Grid` control ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx)).

So if you need another behavior - try to bind the `Visibility` to the `Row.Height` property, or similar, using converter, of course. But notice - when you change the `Visibility` of the `GridSplitter` to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Hidden`, you will not be able to interact with them via mouse/keyborad/[other input device].